# CSS Transition not working as it should (text appears elsewhere)

Tags: html, css

I'm desperately trying to figure this out. I had some help from people on here yesterday which was really appreciated and I am getting somewhere, but for some reason my transition property isn't working as it should. Where I want to be able to hover over a persons image as shown below, the underlying text (that should be there) appears top center of the page for everyone. There should be separate centered text behind each person.

[image: How it works at the moment]

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="meet.css">
    <h1>Meet the Team</h1>
</head>
<body>

<div id="joe" class="info"> 
  <h5>Joe Bloggs</h5>

  <div class="hoverinfo"> <img class="hover" src="DefaultProfile.png" border="0" /> 
    <p class="hovercontent">Test paragraph</p>

  </div>

</div>

<div id="john" class="info"> 
  <h5>John Smith</h5>

  <div class="hoverinfo"> <img class="hover" src="DefaultProfile.png" border="0" /> 
    <p class="hovercontent">Test paragraph</p>

  </div>

</div>

<div id="jane" class="info"> 
  <h5>Jane Doe</h5>

  <div class="hoverinfo"> <img class="hover" src="DefaultProfile.png" border="0" /> 
    <p class="hovercontent">Test paragraph</p>

  </div>

</div>

<div id="joe" class="info"> 
  <h5>Joe Bloggs</h5>

  <div class="hoverinfo"> <img class="hover" src="DefaultProfile.png" border="0" /> 
    <p class="hovercontent">Test paragraph</p>

  </div>

</div>

<div id="john" class="info"> 
  <h5>John Smith</h5>

  <div class="hoverinfo"> <img class="hover" src="DefaultProfile.png" border="0" /> 
    <p class="hovercontent">Test paragraph</p>

  </div>

</div>

<div id="jane" class="info"> 
  <h5>Jane Doe</h5>

  <div class="hoverinfo"> <img class="hover" src="DefaultProfile.png" border="0" /> 
    <p class="hovercontent">Test paragraph</p>

  </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.info {

  display: inline-block;

  width: 32%;

  height: 375px;

  margin-top: 5px;

  text-align: center;

  background: #FFFFFF;

}

.info h5 {

  display: block;

  background: white;

  margin: 0;

}
.hovercontent {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.hoverinfo:hover .hovercontent {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
}
.hoverinfo:hover .hover {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease-out; 
}
```

I'm really not sure how to get it working. Also, ideally, I'd like to keep the page to 3 people in a row if I can and I don't want the image size to change.

Again, any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please invest a bit more details into describing how exactly the result should like? That part is very vague currently...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing position relative to `.info`, that's why the `.hovercontent` is not positioning correctly :

```
.info {
  position: relative;
}
```

Snippet:

```css
.info {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

  width: 32%;

  height: 375px;

  margin-top: 5px;

  text-align: center;

  background: #FFFFFF;

}

.info h5 {

  display: block;

  background: white;

  margin: 0;

}
.hovercontent {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.hoverinfo:hover .hovercontent {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
}
.hoverinfo:hover .hover {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease-out; 
}
```

```html
<div id="joe" class="info"> 
  <h5>Joe Bloggs</h5>

  <div class="hoverinfo"> <img class="hover" src="http://placehold.it/150x375.png" border="0" /> 
    <p class="hovercontent">Test paragraph</p>

  </div>

</div>
<div id="joe" class="info"> 
  <h5>Joe Bloggs</h5>

  <div class="hoverinfo"> <img class="hover" src="http://placehold.it/150x375.png" border="0" /> 
    <p class="hovercontent">Test paragraph</p>

  </div>

</div>
<div id="john" class="info"> 
  <h5>John Smith</h5>

  <div class="hoverinfo"> <img class="hover" src="http://placehold.it/150x375.png" border="0" /> 
    <p class="hovercontent">Test paragraph</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="john" class="info"> 
  <h5>John Smith</h5>

  <div class="hoverinfo"> <img class="hover" src="http://placehold.it/150x375.png" border="0" /> 
    <p class="hovercontent">Test paragraph</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="john" class="info"> 
  <h5>John Smith</h5>

  <div class="hoverinfo"> <img class="hover" src="http://placehold.it/150x375.png" border="0" /> 
    <p class="hovercontent">Test paragraph</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="john" class="info"> 
  <h5>John Smith</h5>

  <div class="hoverinfo"> <img class="hover" src="http://placehold.it/150x375.png" border="0" /> 
    <p class="hovercontent">Test paragraph</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="john" class="info"> 
  <h5>John Smith</h5>

  <div class="hoverinfo"> <img class="hover" src="http://placehold.it/150x375.png" border="0" /> 
    <p class="hovercontent">Test paragraph</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="john" class="info"> 
  <h5>John Smith</h5>

  <div class="hoverinfo"> <img class="hover" src="http://placehold.it/150x375.png" border="0" /> 
    <p class="hovercontent">Test paragraph</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Correct answer, here is a jsfiddle demonstrating that: https://jsfiddle.net/ck640tfs/

Comment: @Herro2689 if my solution is working please mark as solution :p

Answer (score 0):

```css
.info {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

  width: 32%;

  height: 375px;

  margin-top: 5px;

  text-align: center;

  background: #FFFFFF;

}

.info h5 {

  display: block;

  background: white;

  margin: 0;

}
.hovercontent {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.hoverinfo:hover .hovercontent {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
}
.hoverinfo:hover .hover {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease-out; 
}
```

```html
<div id="joe" class="info"> 
  <h5>Joe Bloggs</h5>

  <div class="hoverinfo"> <img class="hover" src="http://placehold.it/150x375.png" border="0" /> 
    <p class="hovercontent">Test paragraph</p>

  </div>

</div>
<div id="joe" class="info"> 
  <h5>Joe Bloggs</h5>

  <div class="hoverinfo"> <img class="hover" src="http://placehold.it/150x375.png" border="0" /> 
    <p class="hovercontent">Test paragraph</p>

  </div>

</div>
<div id="john" class="info"> 
  <h5>John Smith</h5>

  <div class="hoverinfo"> <img class="hover" src="http://placehold.it/150x375.png" border="0" /> 
    <p class="hovercontent">Test paragraph</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="john" class="info"> 
  <h5>John Smith</h5>

  <div class="hoverinfo"> <img class="hover" src="http://placehold.it/150x375.png" border="0" /> 
    <p class="hovercontent">Test paragraph</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="john" class="info"> 
  <h5>John Smith</h5>

  <div class="hoverinfo"> <img class="hover" src="http://placehold.it/150x375.png" border="0" /> 
    <p class="hovercontent">Test paragraph</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="john" class="info"> 
  <h5>John Smith</h5>

  <div class="hoverinfo"> <img class="hover" src="http://placehold.it/150x375.png" border="0" /> 
    <p class="hovercontent">Test paragraph</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="john" class="info"> 
  <h5>John Smith</h5>

  <div class="hoverinfo"> <img class="hover" src="http://placehold.it/150x375.png" border="0" /> 
    <p class="hovercontent">Test paragraph</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="john" class="info"> 
  <h5>John Smith</h5>

  <div class="hoverinfo"> <img class="hover" src="http://placehold.it/150x375.png" border="0" /> 
    <p class="hovercontent">Test paragraph</p>
  </div>

</div>
```